# pg_hba.config me muestra error en el servidor

Tags: php, linux, windows, postgresql, ubuntu

Me estoy conectando a la base de datos a través de una ip desde Linux a Windows pero al ejecutar el proyecto en Linux me muestra el error siguiente, y no se como solucionarlo:

Agradecería el interés.

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no hay una l�nea en pg_hba.conf para
>   �192.168.20.12�, usuario �postgres�, base de datos �db_students�, SSL
>   inactivo
>
> Filename: controllers/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Asi lo tengo en el archivo:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.




# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             10.0.2.15/32            trust
host    all             postgres             192.168.20.12/32    trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        192.168.20.12                 md5
```

Comment: Péganos tu pg_hba para entender mejor. Seguramente te está pidiendo que agregues una línea explícita para esa IP

Comment: publica las líneas referentes a la autentiación que declaraste en el pg_hba.conf

Comment: ya lo he editado

Answer (score 2):

Agrega o editar la siguiente línea en tu `postgresql.conf` :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Agrega la línea siguiente como la primera línea de `pg_hba.conf`. Permite el acceso a todas las bases de datos para todos los usuarios con una contraseña cifrada:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

[revisa la respuesta original en inglés](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84002)

Answer (score 0):

Edita el archivo `pg_hba.conf` en la ruta del servidor:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\data
```

y en la ultima fila agrega tu ip:

```
#host    all             all             172.30.20.12/32            
md5
host    all             all             172.30.20.1/24          
md5
```

Graba y listo.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y gracias por tu respuesta. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece que el problema se solucionaría añadiendo en ese pg_hba.conf la línea

```
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

en la sección de ipv4.

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, el host que estas definido debe ser igual al la ip de tu localhost, seguro estas poniendo una ip de tu red pero no te tu localhost es el mismo ip que te pide PG al momento de crear tu base de datos...

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

hola a todos me ha pasado lo mismo estoy en 29/10/2021 de la nada me sale que no hay una linea para X IP  en la configuracion de hba, si creamos la linea (host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5) estamos dejando abierto para cualquier IP eso no es bueno, en todo casa crie la linea host    all     all     (con el IP  que pedia)       md5. y se soluciono.  saludos

Comment: La sección de respuestas es precisamente para eso, para dar respuestas. Si tienes una pregunta, puedes formular la tuya, y si solo quieres agregar información a las preguntas/respuestas, puedes usar la sección de los comentarios.